# Check for Even/Odd Page in Appendix

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

I have a command that checks to see if the page number of a label is even/odd, using `\ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{mylabel}}}...` that works well. I just came across a situation where I try to use the same command in my appendix, but my command fails.

This is because I've changed the appendix numbering. I use

```
\appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{A.\arabic{page}}
```

to create page numbers like A.1, A.2, etc. The `\isodd` command returns false on all these page numbers.

I'd like to have one command that is able to check for even/odd in both cases - regular and appendix page numbering.

I *may* be open to a different page numbering scheme in the appendix, though it needs to be clearly different than the regular page numbering.

Edit:
Here's minimal code showing the effect I see. On Page 3, it shows it knows which label is on an even/odd page. On Page 6, it shows incorrectly that both are on even pages.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\pagecheck}[1]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{#1}}}{ The label is on an odd page. }{ The label is on an even page. }}
\begin{document}
\section{One}\label{firstsection}
\clearpage
\section{Two}\label{secondsection}
\clearpage
\pagecheck{firstsection}\pagecheck{secondsection}
\clearpage
\appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{A.\arabic{page}}
\section{Appendix A}\label{appA}
\clearpage
\section{Appendix B}\label{appB}
\clearpage
\pagecheck{appA}\pagecheck{appB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post  a full compilable code that we can play with?

Comment: on the first run `mylabel` won't be known so `\pageref` acts as 0 and `\ifodd` will be false, but it should pick up on the second run, the setting of `\thepage` is not used at all, so your `\renewcommand` has no affect on the test

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes a single `.` before the number (when not an integer).

BTW, if you are trying to determine whether the current page is odd or even, you can use the ifoddpage package.  It uses `\arabic{page}` instead of `\thepage`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{refcount}% or hyperref
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\pagecheck}[1]{\edef\mystring{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}%
  \IfInteger{\mystring}{}{\StrBehind{\mystring}{.}[\mystring]}%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\mystring}}{ The label is on an odd page. }{ The label is on an even page. }}
\begin{document}
\section{One}\label{firstsection}
\clearpage
\section{Two}\label{secondsection}
\clearpage
\pagecheck{firstsection}\pagecheck{secondsection}
\clearpage
\appendix
\pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{A.\arabic{page}}
\section{Appendix A}\label{appA}
\clearpage
\section{Appendix B}\label{appB}
\clearpage
\pagecheck{appA}\pagecheck{appB}
\end{document}
```